# How do I report multiple applications or virtual hosts on NewRelic?

Tags: newrelic

How do I report multiple applications or virtual hosts on NewRelic?

NewRelic Shows same server on multiple Application.

Comment: Frequently one single web server is used for supporting more than one application or multiple virtual hosts, and you need to report all of those applications or hosts separately so that you can judge individual performance. You thus need to change the "application name" and possibly other parameters on a host by host, or directory by directory basis. Exactly how this is achieved depends entirely on your actual web infrastructure, and is covered in detail in per directory settings.. Please read that section carefully.

Comment: more detailed information about your application will be required to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

It depends on 1) your application, and 2) your hosting environment.

For example, if your stuff is hosted by Apache, you can change this setting per-vhost in the Apache config.

With a PHP app, you can do something like:

php_value newrelic.appname "Virtual Host 1"

With a Python app, at least via mod_wsgi, you can do:

SetEnv newrelic.app_name "Virtual Host 1"